# Find line number in multiline textbox that contains certain data

Tags: vb.net

I would need a little help.

`Textbox1.Text` contains `1,2,3,4,5,6,17`.

Data in `Textbox2`:

```
Lines 0 = 1,2,3,4,5,7,18
Lines 1 = 21,2,3,4,5,7,19
Lines 2 = 13,11,3,4,5,7,19
Lines 3 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,17
Lines 4 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,21
```

How can I do?

```vb
For Each lines In Textbox2.Lines

Next
```

Expected Output: `Textbox3.Text` contains `3` (Because the combination from `Textbox1` is found on the line 3 in the data).

Comment: ````String.Equals()````  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I can't understand your question, when you say "How can i make?" make what excely?

Comment: to return the corresponding line, on which my combination is found.

Comment: I believe he/she wants to see if the input TextBox text matches the other values (either constants or from additional input)

Comment: If you loop through the Lines, then check it's the same as the other textbox should be a case of a simple `=` comparison, by the looks of it. `If lines = TextBox1.Text` or something like that. To get the `3` output, either set a counter, or use a `For` loop instead of `Foreach` (because it has its own built-in counter). Did you try anything more than what you've written above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use **for each**.

You should iterate over your lines with an index and return the index.

Code exmaple:

```
    For index As Integer = 0 To TextboxX.Lines.Length Step 1
        ' Here you can use your logic to check if the current line (by the index) is correct using TextboxX.Lines(index).
        ' Something like TextboxX.Lines(index) = Textbox1.text
        If TextboxX.Lines(index) = Textbox1.Text Then
            Textbox3.Text = index
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

---

**Bonus**

This logic is already implemented in the framework, and it looks better like this:

```
Textbox3.Text = Array.IndexOf(TextboxX.Lines, Textbox1.Text)
```

Note - if the value was not found **Array.IndexOf** will return **-1**

Comment: Also think about trimming and clearing white space if you just want to compare the numbers, as of right now if there is an extra space in one of the lines then this won't equate to true.

Comment: And ````break;```` is not valid VB.Net It would be ````Exit For````